# How do I properly import RaisesContext from pytest for my type hints?

Tags: python, pytest

I want to use type hints everywhere include my helper functions in my test suite.

A snippet of a function looks like this:

```
def my_helper(
    should_exit: RaisesContext = None,
):
    # do stuff
```

And it is passed a RaisesContext like this:

```
my_helper(pytest.raises(SystemExit))
```

Now `type(pytest.raises(SystemExit))` returns `<class '_pytest.python_api.RaisesContext'>`

This is the only way I could figure out how to import the class:

```
from _pytest.python_api import RaisesContext
```

Is this OK? `_pytest` indicates it should not be referenced directly like this. What is the right way to import this class explicitly so I can use it in my type hints?

Also, I know I don't *need* type hints, but I want to use them and be as explicit with them as I can.

Comment: "Also, I know I don't need type hints, but I want to use them and be as explicit with them as I can." - this is one of the big negative effects type hinting has had on how people write Python. People act like they're mandatory, even though they *know* type hints are completely optional, and they end up importing a bunch of implementation-detail types they're never supposed to access directly, just to write type hints.

Comment: That is ok as there is no other way of importing it. However, since it is the internal pytest class that is not intended to be used outside of it, maybe you should consider rewriting your tests so they don't actually need this helper function that uses the RaisesContext as argument.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @user2357112 and @dsalaj. An alternative is not to accept `RaisesContext` as an argument. Instead, accept an exception:

```py
import contextlib
from typing import Optional

import pytest


def my_helper(should_exit: Optional[Exception] = None):
    if should_exit is None:
        context = contextlib.nullcontext()
    else:
        context = pytest.raises(should_exit)

    with context:
        raise ValueError()


def test_that_will_fail():
    my_helper()


def test_that_will_pass():
    my_helper(ValueError)
```

#### Notes

- The `nullcontext()` is basically a do-nothing context manager
- The code `raise ValueError()` is there for demonstration only. It can be anything which might or might not raise any type of error